# Why does this Powershell Cmdlet return a multidimensional array when parameter comes from pipeline?

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I've written a Powershell cmdlet in C# which returns details about one or more employees' direct manager(s) using a home-grown API.  The cmdlet is supposed to return a collection of one or more objects of type **Associate**.  The problem I'm having is that the output type of the Cmdlet is not consistent.

I designed the Cmdlet such that if you already have a collection of *Associate* objects, you can pass that in via the pipeline. Otherwise, you need to pass in one or more userIds under the *-Identity* parameter.

Here is the behavior I'm seeing, though in terms of the Cmdlet output:

- If I pass in one or more userIds with the *-Identity* parameter, I get the expected collection of *Associate*:

```
    > $test1 = Get-Manager -Identity 'user1','user2'
    > $test1.GetType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     True     List`1                                   System.Object


    PS H:\> $test1 | select displayName

    displayName
    -----------
    John Doe
    Jane Lee
```

- If I pass in one or more *Associate* objects by explicitly using the *-Assoc* parameter, I also get the expected collection

```
    > $folks = Get-Associate 'brunomik','abcdef2'
    > $test2 = Get-Manager -Assoc $folks
    > $test2.getType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     True     List`1                                   System.Object


    PS H:\> $test2 | Select displayName

    displayName
    -----------
    John Doe
    Jane Lee
```

- However, if I pass in a collection of *Associate* objects using the **pipeline**, I seem to get back a multidimensional array!:

```
    > $test3 = $folks | Get-Manager
    > $test3.GetType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


    > $test3 | select displayName

    displayName
    -----------


    ># Select-Object can't find a property called displayName
    ># But if I run GetType() on the first element of the collection:
    > $test3[0].GetType()

    IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    True     True     List`1                                   System.Object

    ># It appears to be yet another collection!
    ># Now, if I run Select-Object on that first element of $test3, I do see the data:
    > $test3[0] | Select displayName

    displayName
    -----------
    John Doe
    Jane Lee
```

Here is the source code for the Cmdlet:

```
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Manager", DefaultParameterSetName = @"DefaultParamSet")]
    [OutputType(typeof(Associate))]
    public class GetManager : Cmdlet
    {
        private Associate[] assoc = null;
        private string[] identity = null;

        private bool assocSet = false;
        private bool identitySet = false;


        //The Assoc parameter supports the pipeline and accepts one or more objects of type Associate
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = @"DefaultParamSet",
                   ValueFromPipeline = true,
                   HelpMessage = "An Associate object as returned by the \"Get-Associate\" cmdlet. Cannot be used with the \"Identity\" parameter")]
        public Associate[] Assoc
        {
            get
            {
                return assoc;
            }
            set
            {
                assoc = value;
                assocSet = true;
            }
        }

        //The Identity parameter accepts one or more string expressions (user IDs)
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = "An Associate user Id. Not to be used with the \"Assoc\" parameter")]
        public string[] Identity
        {
            get
            {
                return identity;
            }
            set
            {
                identitySet = true;
                identity = value;
            }
        }

        //This will contain the output of the Cmdlet
        private List<Associate> Result = new List<Associate>();

        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            base.BeginProcessing();
        }

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            base.ProcessRecord();
            BuildOutputObject();
            WriteObject(Result);
        }

        //Builds the Cmdlet Output object
        private void BuildOutputObject()
        {
            List<Associate> Subordinates = new List<Associate>();

            //Only the Assoc or Identity parameter may be set; not both.
            if (!(assocSet ^ identitySet))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Either the {nameof(Assoc).InQuotes()} or the {nameof(Identity).InQuotes()} parameter must be set, but not both.");
            }

            //If Assoc is set, we already have an array of Associate objects, so we'll simply define Subordinates by calling Assoc.ToList()
            if (assocSet)
            {
                Subordinates = Assoc.ToList();
            }

            //Otherwise, we'll need to create an associate object from each userID passed in with the "Identity" parameter.  The MyApi.GetAssociates() method returns a list of Associate objects.
            else
            {
                Subordinates = MyApi.GetAssociates(Identity);
                if (!MyApi.ValidResponse)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException($"No associate under the identifiers {string.Join(",",Identity).InQuotes()} could be found.");
                }
            }

            //Now, to build the output object:
            Subordinates.ForEach(p => Result.Add(p.GetManager()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProcessRecord` is executed *once per input argument*.

As a result, when you call `Get-Manager -Identity A,B`, PowerShell:

- Resolves the appropriate parameter set (if necessary)
- Invokes `BeginProcessing()`
- Binds value `A,B` to Identity
- Invokes `ProcessRecord()`
- Invokes `EndProcessing()`

When you pipe an equivalent array to it (eg. `"A","B" |Get-Manager`), PowerShell enumerates the input and binds the items to the appropriate parameter *one-by-one* instead - that is, PowerShell:

- Resolves the appropriate parameter set (if necessary)
- Invokes `BeginProcessing()`
- Binds value `A` to `Identity`
- Invokes `ProcessRecord()`
- Binds value `B` to `Identity`
- Invokes `ProcessRecord()`
- Invokes `EndProcessing()`

... resulting in 2 `List<Associate>`'s, instead of one.

The "solution" is to either:

1. *not* return concrete collections types as output objects, or
2. "collect" partial output in `ProcessRecord`, then output once, in `EndProcessing`.

### 1. No wrapping in `IEnumerable` types

This approach closely resembles an *iterator method* in C# - think of `WriteObject(obj);` as PowerShell's version of `yield return obj;`:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    base.ProcessRecord();
    BuildOutputObject();
    foreach(var obj in Result)
      WriteObject(obj);
}
```

`WriteObject()` also has an overload that enumerates the object for you, so the simplest fix is actually just:

```
protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    base.ProcessRecord();
    BuildOutputObject();
    WriteObject(Result, true);
}
```

This first option is *by far* the most preferable, as it allows us to take optimal advantage of performance characteristics of PowerShell's pipeline processor.

### 2. Accumulate output, `WriteObject()` in `EndProcessing()`:

```
private List<Associate> finalResult = new List<Associate>();

protected override void ProcessRecord()
{
    base.ProcessRecord();
    BuildOutputObject();
    # Accumulate output
    finalResult.AddRange(Result)
}

protected override void EndProcessing()
{
    WriteObject(finalResult);
}
```

Omitting the second argument from `WriteObject` and only calling it *once*, will preserve the type of `finalResult`, but you will be blocking any downstream cmdlets from executing until this one is done processing all input

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion did the trick, except for the fact that I'm getting an extra instance of the first manager in the output.  This happens whether I use a loop or the WriteObject() overload.  No a deal breaker, though as I can just use DistinctBy() from MoreLinq to remove any dupes.

Comment: You can solve that with `Result.Clear()` after each `WriteObject()` call :) or by dropping all the indirection, by making `BuildOutputObject()` return its output and then call `WriteObject(BuildOutputObject(), true)` instead (that would be my preference, `Result` is entirely unnecessary)